# Linux password setting change

Tags: password

I need to know how to change the current password setting to become more complex.
My current password setting are very weak the minimum password character number is 1 which it should be at least 8 .

Comment: What do you use to set the password? `passwd` will already not allow simple passwords unless you change it a password as `root`.

Comment: OP question sound like: "where do I tell `passwd` I want uppercase, lowercase, special char and at least 256 char in password, also password should no be reuse within seen years and seven days ? "

Answer (score 4):

It possibly depends on the distribution you use, but on CentOS/RedHat, you can find the default values in `/etc/login.defs`:

```
# Password aging controls:
#
#   PASS_MAX_DAYS   Maximum number of days a password may be used.
#   PASS_MIN_DAYS   Minimum number of days allowed between password changes.
#   PASS_MIN_LEN    Minimum acceptable password length.
#   PASS_WARN_AGE   Number of days warning given before a password expires.
#
PASS_MAX_DAYS   99999
PASS_MIN_DAYS   0
PASS_MIN_LEN    5
PASS_WARN_AGE   7
```

and there's additional constraints you can set with PAM: I find

```
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
```

in my `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, where the pam_pwquality.so does things like the "it is based on a dictionary word" check and `retry` is the number of tries you get on login, but a full introduction to PAM would probably exceed the scope of an answer.

Comment: Thank you all, Ulrich I need to know where can I find password setting in which I could change minimum length of the password to become 8

Comment: @W.sa: well, `/etc/login.def`'s `PASS_MIN_LENGTH` seems like the place to edit.